# How to create a switch statement with print function for enum after creating an instance for it?

Tags: swift, struct

I am trying to finish this assignment for my class and it is giving me a headache. I need a way to create an instance first for the enum and then using a switch statement to print out a string.

Here is the original prompt:

Using the Pet enum provided, create an instance of Pet and then write a switch statement that will print out a different sound (given below) based on which Pet is set to your created instance.

Thanks! I am a beginner!

```
enum Pet { 
      case dog
      case cat
      case bird
      case bunny
 }


 struct Animal {
      var waterAnimal: String
      var otherAnimal: Pet
 }
```

Comment: If you provide your solution I'm sure somebody will be able to help you if you've got any issues but I doubt anybody will solve your assignment for you here, after all it's your assignment you won't learn anything if somebody else solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in the `enum Pet` to get the sound of the Pet. Then in your `Animal` struct you can set the `pet` variable to a specific `pet` and call the `sound()` function to print its sound.

```
enum Pet {

    case dog
    case cat
    case bird
    case bunny

    // Get sound for pet
    func sound() {
        switch self {
        case .dog:
            print("bark")
        case .cat:
            print("meow")
        case .bird:
            print("chirp")
        case .bunny:
            print("bunny sound")
        }
    }

}


struct Animal {

    var pet: Pet = .dog  // Same as –>  var pet = Pet.dog

    func printSound() {

        // Print dog sound
        pet.sound()
    }


}
```

Comment: I guess the only problem is that there is no instance here made for pet such as :

let myPet = Pet(...)

Comment: @Willishere7 `let pet = Pet.dog` and then you just need to `switch pet {`